# A Diophantine problem related to egyptian fractions

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider the following system of equations:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_i=0 
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{a_i}=0
$$
Where for each $i$ $a_i$ is an odd integer and the $a_i$ are not necessarly distinct. A solution $(a_1,\dots,a_{2n})$ is trivial
if (after some permutation of the coefficients) for each $i$ we have 
$$a_i=-a_{n+i}$$.
I know that if $n>2$ there exist non trivial solutions. My questions are:

- What is the minimum number of variables for which there exist non trivial solutions ?
- Can you exhibit a minimal solution or at least a solution you think could be minimal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, -1,3,3,5,5,-15 comes to mind. This is 2n variables for n=3. But you said you know there are non-trivial solutions for n>2. Did you mean "for every n>2" ? If so, what are you asking? Also, why not consider the case of an odd number of integers (some of which would be even)?

Comment: Once you have one solution, you can add +1 and -1 to get one with two more variables.  So with yours, we have solutions for all even n.

Comment: This problem came up while I was dealing with a knot thery problem.
That's why I'm not interested in further generalizations.

I didn't mean for every n>2. 

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution for n=2.  Your equations are $w+x+y+z=0$ and $\frac{1}{w}+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=0$.  Take two variables of the same sign, say $x$ and $y$, and regard them as parameters.  Then we have $zw\frac{x+y}{xy}+(x+y)=0$ or $zw=xy$ and $z+w=-(x+y)$.  This has only the trivial solution.  So the minimum n is 3.

Comment: Ialready knew there are no solutions for n=2, but thanks anyway.